# assigned array value resting when subscribe complete ASP.NET Core Angular spa application

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

values are coming from API call(I have checked by putting console) but the value not assigned to the corresponding array what I have done wrong. API values and ITank having the same case(pascal case).

component.ts

```
tankArray:ITank[];
this.tankService.GetAllMenu()
  .subscribe(resp => {
    this.tankArray = resp;
    console.log(resp);
  });
```

ITank

```
export interface ITank {
  TankId: number;
  TankName: string;
}
```

Service

```
GetAllMenu(): Observable<ITank[]> {
  return this.http.get<ITank[]>(this.rootUrl + 'Tank/GetAllTank');
}
```

Comment: What's your problem?tankArray is empty?Your response from this.tankService.GetAllMenu() has data?

Comment: tankarray is undefined GetALlMenu retrieves data. I have tried to initilize the tak array but the value is not pushing fwhen i subscribe

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tankArray: ITank[] = [];
```

Comment: tried but the values I get from API call not pushing to array

Comment: Can you post the console.log(resp); from  your subscribe  ?

Comment: o: TankName:"s" TankId:1
1: TankName:"p" TankId:2

Comment: why the value I am getting from API call  is not assigning to my tankArray any way I didn't get any error message do you know how to return an error if the value is not set

Comment: when i tried to debug value is assigned but whenever it finish it get cleared I am running this oninit life cycle

Comment: Are you sure that any toher code dosen't affect this tankArray? Can you create a stackBlitz to check it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tankArray:ITank[];
 this.tankService.GetAllMenu()
 .subscribe(resp => {
  this.tankArray = resp;
  console.log(resp);
  }, (error) => console.error(error));
```

You should see the error in the console!

`

Comment: I tried I didn't get any errors but the value still not assigned to tank array but in the resp, console value is displayed

Comment: when i tried to debug value is assigned but whenever it finish it get cleared I am running this oninit life cycle